# jQuery function performance on IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, performance, internet-explorer

I have this function that I use to do hover and focus for each row from two tables displayed in line when cursor pass over and focus on click for each tr. 
It works just fine but I have a problem with IE because is slowing down and I don't understand why. Can anyone tell me how to improve performance for this function?

Check live example: http://mainpage.ueuo.com/

```
function rowSelection(){
        var rows = $('.interactive tr');
        rows.click(function () {
            var i = $(this).GetIndex() + 1; // nth-child is 1-based
            rows.removeClass('selectedRow');
            rows.filter(':nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass('selectedRow');
        });
        rows.hover(function(){
            var i = $(this).GetIndex() + 1;
            rows.filter(':nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass('hoverx');
        },function(){         
            rows.removeClass('hoverx');
        });
    };

jQuery.fn.GetIndex = function(){
    return $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use a CSS-based hover instead? That would perform better in all browsers, particularly IE.

```
.interactive tr:hover td {
    background: lime !important;
}
```

If you want to stick with JavaScript/jQuery, then I recommend you get rid of this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

This is forcing IE to use IE8 mode. IE8 mode is slower than IE9 mode.

Comment: @Dharmesh: If IE6 support is required, he could use (some improved) JavaScript to do this, but *only* for IE6. Why give all browsers the "slow" version, just to cater to the outdated steaming pile of filth that is IE6?

Comment: however in ie8 is not working hover and focus over tr given from css and most important I cannot do that over two tables displayed inline on both tables tr in the same time. check example to understand better.

Comment: I screwed up the selector, sorry about that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".interactive tr").hover(function() {
   $(this).addClass("hoverx");
    }, function() {
   $(this).removeClass("hoverx");
  });

 $(".interactive tr").click(function() {
  $(".interactive tr.selectedRow").removeClass("selectedRow");
     $(this).addClass("selectedRow");
  });​ 
});
```

Comment: Nice, but is not working on both tables, I have two tables displayed in line for which I use my function. Hover and focus it works on the same time on both tables for each row.  check live example with your function (and after try to add in fiddle my function to see right behavior) : http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/41/

Comment: working only on first table , see live example from description to see how it works on both tables in the same time (hover and focus), in your fiddle example it working only on the first table.